# running .z.pg and .z.ps based on client handle request in q

Tags: kdb

I like to write a script that chooses between .z.pg and .z.ps based on the file handle the client chooses and insert the results into the following table:

```
.ipc.history:enlist`startTime`endTime`event`handle`user`query`result`success!(0Np;0Np;`;0Ni;`;::;::;0b)
```

I used the following logic:

```
.ipc.logQuery:{[event;x]
        start:.z.p; r:get x;end:.z.p-start; 0b; //suc:{0b<>@[value;x;0b]};
        `.ipc.history insert (start;end;event;.z.w;.z.u;x;r;0b);r}

.z.pg:.ipc.logQuery`.z.pg;
.z.ps:.ipc.logQuery`.z.ps;
```

I listen on:

```
q queryHistory2.q -p 5050
```

But when the client connects with a command I get `type error:

```
q)h:hopen 5050
q)h"2+2"
'type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type error is coming from 'end' column. You have defined that as a timestamp but when you subtract 2 timestamps, Q returns timespan type.

```
q)  a: .z.p
q)  b: a -1000
q)  type 0N!a-b 
q) (0D00:00:00.000003000 ;-16h)
```

To fix this you need to change type of your column to timespan.

```
q) .ipc.history:enlist`startTime`endTime`event`handle`user`query`result`success!(0Np;0Nn;`;0Ni;`;::;::;0b)

q) `.ipc.history insert(a;.z.p-a;`.z.pg;.z.w;.z.u;"2+2";get "2+2";0b)
```

```
startTime                     endTime              event handle user        query result success
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                            ::    ::     0      
2019.02.12D15:15:55.009781000 0D00:06:21.092914000 .z.pg 0      user "2+2" 4      0
```

Other option is to store nanoseconds(or milliseconds) in your end column instead of timespan.

You could simply convert timespan to nanoseconds by casting it to long.

```
 q)`long$end
```

For this, change your column type to long.

```
 q) .ipc.history:enlist`startTime`endTime`event`handle`user`query`result`success!(0Np;0Nj;`;0Ni;`;::;::;0b)
```

Comment: I tried both options (0Np;0Nn;`;0Ni;`;::;::;0b) and inserting `long$end by " insert (start;`long$end;event;.z.w;.z.u;x;r;suc)"; still getting `type error.

Comment: if you are  using 0Nn for 'end' then just insert end (do not do `long$end). If you want to use nanoseconds(`long$n) then change the 'end' column type to long.

Comment: I did not do them at the same time. Tried each option separately.

Comment: I have updated the answer describing how to define table for second  case. Also are you able to run the example I have mentioned in your Q session?

Comment: Also you need to redefine .z.pg and .z.ps after changing the function (if not done already).  .z.pg:.ipc.logQuery`.z.pg;

Comment: I changed to (0Np;0Nj;`;0Ni;`;::;::;0b) and left end as end. I logged out of q session and retyped q queryHistory2.q -p 5050 to redefine `.z.pg. Still no good. But your example works fine.

Comment: case 1. when you use 0Nj then use `long$end in insert command. case 2. when you use 0Nn then use end in insert command.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot